# How can I change the size of my npm slider angular?

Tags: angular, npm, slider

[Here we have the code from Angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOLY0.png)

[Here we have the npm slider i found on npm.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiYOm.png)

I don't know how to modify the margin of the pictures cause, they got stick, and also i don't know with the specifications of https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-image-slider how to change the size and other elements pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the imageSize property: Set slider images width, height and space. space is use for set space between slider images. Pass object like {width: 400, height: 300, space: 4} or if you only want to set space then pass space only {space: 4}